# HBase Table Secondary Indexing Issue

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-phoenix, ambari

I am using Hbase of V2.0.2. I am trying to create Secondary Indexing for the same table using below commands.

```
create_index ‘idx’, ‘HBase_table’, {INDEXED_COLUMNS => ['cf:CN','cf:CN']}
```

But I am getting the below error for this.

```
NameError: uninitialized constant INDEXED_COLUMNS.
```

I have tried in another way also like below,

I have added the below properties from Ambari to the HBase Custome HBase-site.xml file.

```
 <property>
        <name>hbase.regionserver.class</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.IndexedRegionInterface</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.regionserver.impl</name>
        <value>
        org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.tableindexed.IndexedRegionServer
        </value>
    </property>
```

After that Region servers are getting down Without any errors.